# Firebase callback does not fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I have this Firebase reference to retrieve all the pending (unread) messages by passing the priority of last read message. I do this onload of the chat room.

```
NSNumber* lastPriority = [self getLastPriority];
__block FirebaseHandle handle = [[msgListRef queryStartingAtPriority:lastPriority] observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

    // here I will get all the pending messages and add them to my local message list and reload the UITableView
    [self addMessageToList: snapshot]
    [msgListRef removeObserverWithHandle:handle];
    // Then I call the below function to keep listening for new messages when the chat is in progress
    [self addMessageListener];

}];



- (void) addMessageListener{
        msgListRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:messageListUrl];
        NSNumber* lastPriority = [self getLastPriority];
        [[msgListRef queryStartingAtPriority:lastPriority] observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

            [self addMessageObject:snapshot.value];
            // Here I will reload the table view. This one is supposed to fire for each       
            //message since I used FEventTypeChildAdded. 
            //*** BUT THIS CALLBACK IS NEVER FIRED ***

        }];
}
```

Any idea why the second callback with FEventTypeChildAdded observerType never gets fired when I already called FEventTypeValue before that? It works if I don't read all with  FEventTypeValue. But in that case my UITableView reload will get called for each pending messages when the user enters the chat room.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using lastPriority and not lastMessage.priority? Also, what is the value of the priority? And how many messages exist with that priority?

Comment: that was a typo in the question. I will edit it. The priority is a running number that I increment everytime a new message comes in. it is also stored in a firebase location.

Comment: I'd also double check that the priority you're passing to the child event handler is the same as the value event handler. Is addMessageToList modifying the last priority somehow?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your code is trying to do from the snippet.  What's the difference between `addMessageToList` and `addMessageObject`?  Is the value of `msgListRef` changing?  At any rate, it might simplify things a little if you use `observeSingleEventOfType` instead of `observeEventType`, so you can get rid of the `removeObserverWithHandle` call (I don't actually see a problem with it, but it's hard to reason about what that does since it uses a shared variable and gets executed inside a block).

Comment: Hi Chris, I wish to use observeSingleEventOfType but that way I cannot query from a specifc priority. I saw this as this is given in the firebase documentation on how to remove the observer immediately as an example. addMessageToList will loop through all the items and add to the list. addMessageObject will add single item. Sorry for not explaining in detail..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry guys.The issue was with my code. The firebase reference (msgListRef) was re-initilized at another function that I didnt notice.